# About norms in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $H$ be a Real Hilbert, $a,b \in H \backslash\{0\}$ orthogonals $T:H\rightarrow H$ defined as follows:
$T(x) :=a(x,b)+b(x, a)$. Calculate $||T||$.

I think $||T|| = ||a|| ||b||$, so I already proved that $||T||\geq ||a|| ||b||$ via Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and letting $x=a$ but... I don't know how to prove the reverse inequality.

Note: My best attempt was $||T||\leq \sqrt2||a|| ||b||$, is there any idea or hint to kill that $\sqrt 2$ and get the desired inequality?

Comment: Using Cauchy-Schwarz, you should get $\| T \| \leq \|a\|\|b\|$. And for $x = a$, you can see what happens.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I can't see how :/

Comment: How do you get $\| T \| \geq \|a \| \| b \|$?

Comment: $|T(a)||=||b(a,a)+a(a,a)||=||b ||a||^2||=||b|| ||a||^2$, hence by CS-ineq $||b|| ||a||^2 = ||T(a)|| \leq  ||T|| ||a||$, therefore $||T||\geq ||a|| ||b||$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $e_1=\frac a {\|a\|}$ and $e_2=\frac b {\|b\|}$. Then $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is orthonormal so $\|x\|^{2} \geq (x,e_1)^{2}+(x,e_2)^{2}$. Hence, $(x,a)^{2}/(\|a\|^{2})+(x,b)^{2}/(\|b\|^{2})\leq \|x\|^{2}$. Can you show now that $\|Tx\|^{2}\leq \|a\|^{2}\|b\|^{2}\|x\|^{2}$?

Hint for proving that $\|x\|^{2} \geq (x,e_1)^{2}+(x,e_2)^{2}$: Just expand $0 \leq \|x-(x,e_1)e_1-(x,e_2)e_2\|^{2}$.

Comment: $\|x\|^{2} \geq (x,e_1)^{2}+(x,e_2)^{2}$ because we're in $\mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @Crimmi

Comment: well... $(x,a)^{2}/(\|a\|^{2})+(x,b)^{2}/(\|b\|^{2})\leq \|x\|^{2}$ iff $||b||^2(x,a)^{2}+||a||^2(x,b)^{2}\leq \|x\|^{2}||a||^2||b||^2$ but LHS it's equivalent by orthogonality to: $||Tx||^2$, hence we're done!!
My only question is how I know the first inequality you gave me is true?

Comment: For any orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ in a real Hilbert space $\|x\|^{2} =\sum (x,e_n)^{2}$. Without completeness you get $\geq $ since any orthonormlla set can be extended to  an orthonormal basis  @Crimmi

Comment: First I thought by Cauchy-schawarz so $(x,e_i)^2\leq ||x||^2$ for $i=1,2$ taking the sum $(x,e_1)^2+ (x,e_2)^2\leq  2||x||^2$ and again my problem with $\sqrt 2$ :/
Edit: I think, that result is even more powerfull than Cauchy Schwarz, so may have sense. Is there any bibliography where I can found that theorem about orthonormal basis in Real Hilbert Spaces?

Comment: You are missing a fundamental fact about orthonormal sets. Do you know the identity in my previous comment?  I have also added a proof of the inequality to my answer. @Crimmi

Comment: Yes, I was missing it. Is there any link or book to see a proof of that identity, even more, I can proof I want with chains of if and only if, right? @Kavi

Comment: @Crimmi See the section on 'Orthonormal sets' in Rudin's RCA. The inequality is in the very first theorem of this scetion. In fact any treatment of Hilbert spaces will surely have this fact somewhere.